# An existing eCommerce solution VS Custom built

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm about to launch a few online stores and I would like to share my thoughts so everyone can benefit and also was wondering about your opinion related to the question: open-source eCommerce vs custom built.

I've been exploring some the existing solutions (Magento, OpenCart, OSCommerce, Xcart).

Advantages and cons:

**Existing solutions:**

*Advantages:*

- You don't maintenance the code.
- Plug and Play extensions.
- Support.
- Less code hours (not so sure about that anymore).

*Cons:*

- Hard to custmoize: custom templates, plugins, special needs has to be implented over an heavy code already (not a MVC fan).
- Too many features (could reduce performance).

**Custom built:**

*Advantages:*

- Easy theme customization (no limits).
- Lightweight.
- More secure (questionable: Minimal is more secure, though existing solutions has more pen-testers == Users/Coders).
- Easy work-around.

*Cons:*

- Hours, a lot of them.
- Lack of plugins, you need to craft everything yourself.

More things to consider:

1. If I'm going for the custom built - which PHP framework would help me the must?
2. Do you know any existing solution which is lightweight, has good plugins database, and is easy to customize?

at the moment I have to 'like' custom built more, since i'm going to built a network of stores and would like to get a customized solution, though wondering if I might be wrong.

Please, share from your experience and your thoughts related,

Thanks in advance, your help is appreciated.

Sagi.

Comment: instead of starting from scratch i suggest to go for extension of well build framework.A good framework always provides point of extension.So in place of putting efforts on starting to ground zero start from what specific you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few things to consider, in addition to what you stated.

Developing a new eCommerce solution requires not only manpower, but also knowledge. Many topics require dedicated knowledge. Some examples:

- Integration of payment systems requires knowledge about federal laws, about the regulations for VISA and Mastercard
- Integration of customer systems requires knowledge of encryption systems, of federal regulations for personified data, of opt-in and opt-out customer relation systems
- Integration of interfaces to other solutions (ERP, CRM) requires knowledge of secure transactions and channels, secure authentication, transport layer security

Many of the solutions available on the market already have most of this down. If not, they usually don't gain a competitive market share. Some swipe these requirements under someone elses carpet, Magento is known for redistributing it to writers of plugins.

Comment: As far as the must ease platform to customize? (templates, build plugins)

Comment: Customization is non-trivial in most systems. Magento has a great technique for that, but is difficult to understand fully. OSCommerce is a little bit easier, but complex things are more of a hazzle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confused between open source or Custom eCommerce solution then I would advice you to choose Custom eCommerce solution. The reason behind this is that if you choose Custom eCommerce solution then the end product that you will see is fully according to you that will satisfy your requirements.
Its true that you have to pay a bit more than a normal eCommerce solution but you will get a powerful and engaging Online Store that will also help you to generate good revenues and sales.
If you are looking for a Smart eCommerce Solution but still confused about choosing then Go for a [FATshoppe eCommerce System](http://fatshoppe.com) and check the demo website of your Online Store.